# How to "subclass" a PSQL query to increase performance/improve readability?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

So currently, I need to run multiple queries with a template of

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) 
FROM inventory_item
WHERE instance_type = (sell/buy)
```

Right now I would have to run that 5 times, once for each `instance_type` aside form sell/buy.

Is there a way to condense it so that I could get all results once without having to run multiple queries? Basically have it look something like

```
SELECT SUM(a.quantity) AS sell, SUM(b.quantity) AS buy
FROM inventory_item a, b
WHERE a.instance_type = 'sell'
WHERE b.instance_type = 'buy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT instance_type, SUM(a.quantity) AS quantity
FROM inventory_item a GROUP BY instance_type;
```

This will return a result like:

```
instance_type | quantity
-------------------------
sell          | 250.0
buy           | 128.5
```

Comment: You're a life saver Clemens, works like a charm! Thank you so much. I'll accept your answer when I'm allowed to do so in 7 minutes.